# Directly connecting to working default AspNetSqlProvider Database in App_Data? It's not visible

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

Working on a project for myself doing OpenID integration with a simple MVC3 RC2 webapp.

I'm using AspNetSqlProvider as the provider, and asp.net configuration can see / modify the database (add users / roles, etc.)

My next step was to add a table to the DB to store userIDs to OpenIDs.

However, I cannot see the database under the App_Data folder in my solution. Previously with ASP.NET / VS 2010 I thought I remembered being able to click on the DB file under that directory in my solution to connect to it.

Does anyone have an idea why it is there and works and yet I'm unable to see it in my VS solution?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!